# Cakephp 2.1 Plugin not detect Model Package

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

at first sorry my bad English

I want load model in my plugin controller

i have a controller in this path:

/app/Plugin/Services/Controller/TypesController.php

and i have a model in this path:

/app/Plugin/Services/Model/ServiceType.php

i want load ServiceType model in TypesController, i use:

$this->loadModel("ServiceType");

this command not detect my ServiceType model but this command point to my main Model pacake to this path:

/app/Model/ServiceType.php

but i want load Model in my plugin Model. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if that is you primrary model you should be using

```
$uses = array('Services.ServiceType');
```

If not you still need to use the plugin prefix:

```
$this->loadModel("Services.ServiceType");
```